# How to output data to an excel file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-interop

How do I output data from a list that has a value within and output that data to an excel file. This is my first time doing this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1):

Please see the following Stack Overflow which walks you through step by step how to do this: [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

The instructions provided take you through using the open source library [ExcelLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)

Answer (score -2):

I am on mobile so I can't link this, but I do believe you can output data values separated by commas "," and when you open that file the commas represent one cell.. so

"1456, 1745" should open up as two cells with those values

Comment: He is asking about outputting to an Excel file, not a csv.